# Make django-wysiwyg work on django pages

Tags: django, wysiwyg, textfield, django-wysiwyg

I have a `TextField` for description on one of my forms, and i want to apply reich text editor for that so tried to use [this package](https://github.com/pydanny/django-wysiwyg), but i am unable to make it work

below are my settings

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    .....
    ..... 
    # Description Rich text editor settings
    'tinymce',
    'django_wysiwyg',
)

DJANGO_WYSIWYG_FLAVOR = "tinymce"
```

**template.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load wysiwyg %}
{% wysiwyg_setup %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'product_create' %}" method="post">

    <div class="marg_tp38 span12">
         {{product_form.name}}
         {% wysiwyg_editor 'id_name' %}
    </div>
    <div class="marg_tp38 span12">
         {{product_form.description}}
         {% wysiwyg_editor 'inputdescription_id' %}
    </div>
</form>
```

So above are my settings that i have used, but i could n't able to make that work, can anyone please let me know what am i missing ? and what should be done in order to make it work ?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, are there any errors in console, smth is not displayed correctly? What is it?

Comment: yeah exactly i am getting some erros in chrome console like tinymce not found, wysiwyg not found

Comment: Have you installed `django-tinymce`?

Comment: yeah installed both tinymce, wysiwyg and placed in installed apps, when i do pip freeze i can able to see them there in my env

Comment: Ok, please show the error message (containing the wrong url) and also provide all settings values related to static files and how you deliver static in your urls.py..

Answer (score 1):

- Move {% wysiwyg_setup %} in head section
- Make sure you have copied tinymce in static folder, and set correct path for DJANGO_WYSIWYG_MEDIA_URL in settings as mentioned on [documentation](http://django-wysiwyg.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html).